# UIButton image gets distorted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to make my UIButton on my Navigation Controller bar. However, when I try to do this my image get's distorted.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
UIButton *sampleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[sampleButton setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sampleButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"but.png"] [sampleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pushNav)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:sampleButton];
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm on the brink of madness, lol. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never-mind, I finally figured it out. lol... you have to use CGRectMake differently depending on if your adding the button as an item or not.

```
[sampleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,32,90,32)];
```

90 stretches the image to the needed length.

Make sure you don't add the sampleButton to the nav bar as an item to make the above code won't work like needed.

Comment: If you answer your answer yourself, you should provide the answer for future readers.